# wait for an array of Ajax Requests to be done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array with filenames and i need to retrieve all those files with ajax requests and wait for them to finish to initialize my stencil.

```
$.when(req[0],req[1],req[2],req[3],req[4],req[5],req[6],req[7]).done(function(){
    for (var i in arr) 
        Stencil.push(new Platform(importedData[i].cells[0]));                             

    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
})
```

AS you can see i fixed the number of the request to wait for, and it's no good. How can i wait for all thoses requests dynamically, the number of the requests is the length of my array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `when` to an array like this:

```
$.when.apply($, req).done(function(){

    for (var i in arr) 
       Stencil.push(new Platform(importedData[i].cells[0]));                             
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");

});
```

The array has to be filled with jQuery promises, so best to use the result of a function that processes one file and returns a promise and store those in the array.

*If you can provide more information about what you do with the files, I will update the example to match.*

Here is a little sample that simulates asyc file processing (using a timer):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/79bp8yw1/

```
var files = ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"];

var req = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    req.push(processFile(files[i]));
}

$.when.apply($, req).done(function(){
    $('#body').append("All done");
});
```

and the dummy file processing function returns a promise:

```
var time = 1000;
function processFile(filename){
    var def = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('body').append("File " + filename + "<br/>");
        def.resolve();
    }, time);
    time += 1000;
    return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thank you !  $.when.apply worked for me !
As for your second answer i don't quite get it, i'm trying to retreive JSON Data with AJAX request ( which represent an object in my stencil, each one of them ) and i need to wait for all those ajax requests to complete to push them in my Stencil .

So i don't get why you need to set a timer. You fix a timeout for an ajax request to complete ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill an array with all the promises returned from those AJAX calls, then apply that to the `$.when`. Try this:

```
$.when.apply($, req).done(function() {
    // your logic here...
});
```

Comment: your answer is correct too it worked for me but i choose trueblueaussie as an answer because its more elaborate . Thank you